# Installing TFS Express on win 2003 server

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to setup TFS express on a win 2003 server (32 bits) but it throw me this errors

```
Error : TF400154: No se admite la instalación en esta versión de Windows.
Error : TF400155: Solamente se admiten versiones de 64 bits de Windows Server.
```

Already have TFS installed on WIN7 (32bits) and it works fine.

There is a way to install it on my win 2003 server machine ?

---

Bad translation:

> Error : TF400154: Installation is not allowed on this version of Windows.
>   Error : TF400155: Only 64-bit versions of Windows Server are allowed.

Comment: Juan, please translate those messages into English.

Comment: Also, do you have TFS 2012 installed on Windows 7 32-bit?

Comment: There could easily be a constraint in the installer, not allowing windows 2003 32 bit installations. Did you check platform requirements for your tfs product?

Comment: @Juan: please correct my translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to install it, TFS 2012  only can be installed in 64 bits  server platforms

```
Server operating systems:

   64-bit version of Windows Server 2008   with SP2

   64-bit versions of Windows Server 2008 R2 ¹ with SP1

   64-bit versions of Windows Server 2012 ²
```

The complete requirements here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592.aspx

Comment: Actually that is not what that link now states.  You should be able to install TFS2012 on 32-bit Server 2008 (SP2).  Reality is that you still cannot.