# TFS 2008 - 2012 upgrade can't install SharePoint extensions

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, windows-server-2003, tfs-migration

I am testing an upgrade from TFS 2008 to TFS 2012.  Currently I'm using SharePoint 2007 on a separate server, running Windows Server 2003 Enterprise x64 Edition w/ SP2.  I do NOT want to upgrade SharePoint as part of the TFS upgrade.

My understanding is that to continue to use SharePoint with TFS 2012, the TFS extensions must be installed on the SharePoint server...

When running the tfs_sharePointExtensions.exe, I immediately get an error message that:

> Error : TF400436 : Team Foundation Server Extensions can only be installed on a Server Operating Systems.
> TFS setup did not detect an existing instance of SharePoint installation on this machine.
> TFS SharePoint Extensions cannot be installed on a 32-bit operating system unless SharePoint is already installed.
> Either install SharePoint manually on this machine, or run this installation on a 64-bit OS and we will install SharePoint for you.

In the installation log I see these lines:

> Condition 'TFSDev10Installed' evaluates to false.
>
> Condition 'NOT ((NTProductType = 3
> AND (VersionNT64 = v6.0 OR VersionNT64 = v6.1 OR VersionNT64 = v6.2))
> OR (VersionNT = v6.0 AND NTProductType = 3 AND
> (SharePoint12_32bitExists OR SharePoint12_64bitExists OR
> SharePoint14Exists)))' evaluates to true.
>
> [Error] TF400436 : Team Foundation
> Server Extensions can only be installed on a Server Operating Systems.
> TFS setup did not detect an existing instance of SharePoint
> installation on this machine. TFS SharePoint Extensions cannot be
> installed on a 32-bit operating system unless SharePoint is already
> installed.  Either install SharePoint manually on this machine, or run
> this installation on a 64-bit OS and we will install SharePoint for
> you.

This is clearly a server OS, 64bit, with SharePoint installed and running, so it isn't clear to me how I might be able to correct this.  I haven't been able to get any guidance using Google.

Any ideas on what I might need to do to be able to continue with the SharePoint extensions installation?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the Server 2003 you can not install TFS2012 (or it's SharePoint-Extension) on Windows Server 2003

See Requirements:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd578592%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

or this:
[Installing TFS Express on win 2003 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220961/installing-tfs-express-on-win-2003-server)

Maybee you can try to Install the SharePoint extensions for TFS 2010 and try to connect them with your TFS 2012. Maybee this work.

Regards