# Team Foundation In Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed visual studio 2010 and created an asp.net project.Now me and my colleague want to work in that same project with version control. I want to connect to a team foundation.

I dont have an idea....

So please let me know how to do this..

Thanks in Advance
BAGEESH

Answer (score 0):

first begin by installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1, then this upgrade pack: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082

The pack lets you connect to TFS 2012 from VS 2010 SP1.

Next, download and install TFS 2012 express (the free one) on your server.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38190

Install guides are here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29035

If you want to go the simpler route, you can use Team Foundation *Service*, which is the cloud-based version that is currently free for up to 5 users.
http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-online-Overview-vs

Forgive me for not going into too much detail, as all of the sites I was familiar with seem to have been pushed aside to make way for all the 2013 models.

**Update - June 2016**

Microsoft would like you to know that Team Foundation Service is now known as Visual Studio Team Services.  And while the link I supplied above for pricing will redirect you to the proper location, the new url is: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-pricing-vs

Comment: I have downloaded the files...but it doesn't supports in MS Windows Server 2008 32 bit

Comment: what doesn't?  I'm running all of the above except the TFS Server on Windows Server 2003 32-bit...

Comment: it  showing "Error Tf400155 : only 64-bit version of windows server are supported"

Comment: it looks like you'll need to use the cloud version, then.  TFS 2012 can only be installed on 64 bit - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220961/installing-tfs-express-on-win-2003-server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow theses steps

1. Go to `FILE Tab` of Visual Studio, select `Source Control` section, click link `Add Solution to Source Control`.
2. Enter the url of your server.
3. Your `Team Project Collection` must appear (Collection project is set of team projects)
4. Click on your Team Project and validate with `Connect` button

Remark : Ensure that you have installed  this patch : http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=29082

Comment: I happy to help you bageesh